# How to add selected item to text block

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app.
I created 1 list box for `months`. When the user clicks on any `month` (eg. May), then the text block should get that value.

My question is; How do I add this selected value to text block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

XAML:

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="ListBox"/>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    private readonly string[] _months = new[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBox.ItemsSource = _months;
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PageTitle.Text = (string)ListBox.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```